# Polynomial Regression using sliding windows?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to predict a stock's closing price for the next week using linear regression and a sliding window.

This is an example of the database I'm working with...

```
Week_Number Year    Open      Close   
    0       2020    46.270000   46.045000   
    1       2020    46.748001   47.506000     
    2       2020    50.888000   51.382000     
    3       2020    52.724999   52.530000
    4       2020    49.892001   49.424001
```

I've managed to create the model using polyfit, now I want to implement it in a sliding window, so that for whatever window value(W), it predicts closing price for W+1.

Was thinking of putting this in a function than using .rolling() and .apply() to implement the function, but not sure if this is correct or where to go from here.

The idea here is to change the window size and poly degree to see what fits best.

This is what I have so far..

```
X = df_20['Open'].values 

y = df_20['Close'].values

def regression(x,y,degree):
    model = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    predict = np.poly1d(model)
    return(predict(*Closing Price here*)
 

x = df_20[['Open', 'Close']].rolling(window = 3).apply(regression, args = )
```

This code is obviously incomplete, not sure if I'm tackling it the right way or if it's even possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Reading "linear regression" and "poly degree" in the same context feels wrong. Otherwise you seem to be on the right track. Is there any specific problem you're running into?

Comment: It's a homework task in which I have test different degree of fits for prediction. I'm not sure how to implement the 'apply' function with a regression model and if that's even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem but a window sliding may easily be accomplished with 'slicing' of your arrays.
For example, regression( x[-5:], y[-5:], d) would analyze the last 5 days.
And if you do backtesting, regression( x[t:t+5], y[t:t+5], d) will analyse 5 older days.